# How do I use my ansible host_var in my jinja2 template?

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2, devops

I'm new at jinja2 template and ansible and I'm trying to make a Jinja2 template to configure my firewalld on Centos using ansible

My host_vars looks like :

```
---
fw_zones:
  - name: zone_admin
    ports:
      - 333/tcp
      - 555/udp
```

And I would like to get something like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <source address="192.168.1.1/24"/>
  <port port="333" protocol="tcp"/>
  <port port="555" protocol="udp"/>
</zone>
```

So I tried to build my Jinja2 template but I can't manage to make it work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <source address="192.168.1.1/24"/>
{% for port in ports %}
  <port port="{{ ports }}" protocol="?"/>
{% endfor %}
</zone>
```

I tried to use things like fw_zones.ports fw_zones.zone_admin.ports
But it seems that he can't find the value I'm asking for :( Did I make something wrong ?

Is there a way to use my vars and is there a way to separate my port and my protocol ?

Also, Do you guys have sa tool to try my template ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <source address="192.168.1.1/24"/>
{% for port in fw_zones[0].ports %}
  <port port="{{ port.split("/")[0] }}" protocol="{{ port.split("/")[1] }}"/>
{% endfor %}
</zone>
```

However maybe you also have to filter specific element under `fw_zones`, then you can try to add `if` statement to filter specific element name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <source address="192.168.1.1/24"/>
{% for element in fw_zones %}
{% if element.name == "zone_admin" %}
{% for port in element.ports %}
  <port port="{{ port.split("/")[0] }}" protocol="{{ port.split("/")[1] }}"/>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</zone>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Seems to work well, I'm not sure I understand the second part, 
Does it mean if I have something like :

```
---
fw_zones:
  - name: zone_admin
    ports:
      - 333/tcp
      - 555/udp
  - name : zone_2
    ports:
      - 444/tcp
      - 777/udp
```
I can choose wish part I want ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's the case.